# roundedCorner on UIImageView applies incorrectly to UITableCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, rounded-corners

Hi there I have a table cell which contains amongst other things a UIImageView. I want to make this UIImageView have a rounded corner. Here's the code that I have (relevant snippets):

```
UIImageView* image;
image = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:0]; // get the UIImageView from the nib
image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData]; // imagedata contains the image
image.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
image.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

When I do this, the entire UITableViewCell gets the rounded corners, instead of the UIImageView (see attached image).

Can someone tell me why the rounded corners are applied to the table cell rather than the uiImageView?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnkyQ.png

Comment: Because you set the rounded corner stuff to the cell, instead of the image. You need to get the reference to the Image if you want to set the image "rounded corner" look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:0];`

In `cell` subviews you have only `UITableViewCellContentView` with `tag == 0`.

You can manually add the UIImageView to cell.

Comment: Thank you! That was it - I ended up removing the UIImageView from the NIB and created my own, and called [cell addSubview:imageView];

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be the `...Tag:0`:

```
image = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:0]; // get the UIImageView from the nib
```

If you are using a non-custom `UITableViewCell` replace that line with:

```
image = (UIImageView*)[cell imageView];
```

Else, replace the tag number.